# Calculating date value based on a column value

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I've been doing a lot of research and struggling to get the syntax down for "Column B." Any help is appreciated.

"Column A" is a manually entered date "ddmmyyyy." I want to calculate "Column B" automatically based on this date. If "Column A" is before March 1, 2016 the result in "Column B" should be [Column A]+100, if after March 1, 2016 the result should be [Column A]+50. The +100/50 represents days added to the date in "Column A."

Edit: Thanks for the responses. Column A is a date field set to date and time format, would that make a difference?

I input the formula as =IF([A]<1/3/2016,[A]+100,A+50) and the output is only providing the +50 regardless of date, unless Column A is blank in which case the result is +100. Any suggested changes appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others are forgetting to convert 3/1/2016 to an actual date so it can compare to Column A. Here is your formula:

`=IF([Column A]<DATE(2016,3,1),[Column A]+100,[Column A]+50)`

Answer (score 2):

The formula you are looking should be something along the lines of this:

```
=IF(A<1/3/2016,A+100,A+50)
```

Set the column to return date.

SharePoint calculated columns are just excel formulas (with some restrictions) and as such if you search for excel formulas/make your own in excel you can usually port them over into SP with no problem.

Comment: Thomas, note that this will work as long as Column A is a date field (not a string ddmmyyyy).

Comment: Column A is a date field set to date and time format, would that make a difference?                                                                                                 I input the formula as =IF([A]<1/3/2016,[A]+100,A+50) and the output is only providing the +50 regardless of date, unless Column A is blank in which case the result is +100.

Comment: You can shorten the logic to ``= A + IF( A<1/3/2016 , 100 , 50 )``  If 1/3/2016 is misinterpreted because of locale setttings you can use the DATE function to ensure a correct Date: ``DATE( year , month , day  ) ``  More at: http://viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Answer (score 0):

A calculated column is not the best way to do this; a workflow is. You want Column A and Column B to be Date/Time fields. Then write a workflow on create and edit that checks whether Column A is less than 3/1/2016. If so, add 100 days, else add 50 days (using Add Time to Date action). Then set Column B equal to the output variable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I don't have the ability to create custom workflows under our permissions so I was hoping to implement this with a calculated column.

Comment: Roland's formula will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
IF([Column A]<1/3/2016, "[Column A]+100", "[Column A]+50")
```

Comment: This will not work with quotes around the date calculations